# How is this technology called? Bidirectional AJAX implementation

Tags: javascript, ajax, gmail, push, pull

Some time ago I read an article about bidirectional AJAX implementations.
It's supposed to be used by Gmail but it's not comet.

It works like this:

- Client makes AJAX call
- Server sleeps until some event occurs
- Server responds
- Repeat

It was a short name... I need it really bad for a paper I'm writing.
Any help will be appreciated.

Best Regards

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[long polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#Long_polling)

Comment: What's the difference to comet?

Comment: Umm. To quote from the paragraph that the link in my answer points to: In a web/AJAX context, long polling is also known as Comet programming

Comment: it's exactly that, but it had a name, a single-worded name like "comet" but it wasn't comet.

Comment: Looks like a duck, quacks like a duck, …. Whatever it was, it sounds exactly like Comet. They might have called it something else, but that's probably because it just predated the term catching on.

Answer (score 0):

According to wikipedia

> "Comet is known by several other names, including **Ajax Push**,
>   **Reverse Ajax**, **Two-way-web**, **HTTP Streaming**, and **HTTP server push** among others."

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29